# html file is showing all NUL characters when open in notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

I had a html file which I was editing in dreamviewer and inbetween electricity went off,now when I open the file it shows all the "NUL" characters and I am not able to see anything. It does show the size as 27KB.

Please help.[image]

Comment: Press the Windows key. Type `File history`. Find your file. You did set up File history, didn't you?

Comment: No I have not. Is that file got corrupted?

Comment: However, more than likely you are going to have to accept that it is gone. But you can try a last change on notepad++ click on file and see below. If locally your file is there.
One que did you download this file from server ??

Comment: @MostafaBaezid No, it was there locally on my system.

Comment: so you open it once in browser for how it looks ??